# AngularFire 2 "child_added" returning all childs

Tags: firebase, angular6, angularfire2

I'm having difficulties in understanding the `"child_added"` from angularfire2.

According to the documentation, the `"child_added"`, should return all children the first time, and then listen only for new children added to that particular db node.

With my code, the first time I get all children as expected. The problem is when I add a new child to the `userinfo` node, I still get all the children (including the newly added).

Does this mean that the `"child_added"` is actually downloading all the children every time a new child is added?

**My db structure**

[image]

**.ts code (relevant part)**

```
 ngOnInit(){
   this.userService.getUsers().snapshotChanges(['child_added'])
     .subscribe(users => {        
       users.forEach(user=> {
         console.log(user.key)
       })
     })
 }
```

**The service (relevant part)**

```
 constructor(private firebaseApp: AngularFireDatabase) {}

 getUsers(){
   return this.firebaseApp.list('userinfo/')
 }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're returning a new list every time `getUsers` is called, the `child_added` event will fire on each user in that list.

If you want to only fire all users the first time and after that get changes, you should probably create the list only once and return it from there on:

```
var usersList;

constructor(private firebaseApp: AngularFireDatabase) {}

getUsers(){
  if (!this.usersList) {
    this.usersList = this.firebaseApp.list('userinfo/')
  }
  return this.usersList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `getUsers()` is actually called only once at `ngOnInit()` (I updated my question accordingly). The thing I want to understand is if the `child_added` actually re-downloads the whole list from the database, or only the new child which then gets added to the previously created list.

Comment: Whether you use `child_added` or `value` doesn't matter, the client will ensure that all data in that location/query is available in the client. But if you have two listeners on that location, it'll only get the data once. So as long as you keep the list (as in my code above), the data will remain available in the client. But if destroy the existing list (and listener) and create a new list every time, the data is gone from memory and will be reloaded each time. It's probably easiest to see this in the Network tab of your browser, as all traffic goes over web sockets.

Comment: You're right thank you. So when  `usersList` already exists, `getUsers` will simply return `usersList`, with the addition of of new child. So `userList` will hold all the children all the time, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, but that's always the case no matter how you initialize it. The difference is that a new list will fire `child_added` for each child, and possibly have to read it from the server (if the data isn't present on the client yet).